# Log Retention for AppSync in CloudFormation

Tags: logging, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to find out, whether it is possible to set log retention for appsync log groups using CloudFormation. According to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-appsync-graphqlapi-logconfig.html) for `LogConfig`, there is no such thing as log retency parameter. Does anyone know any other way?

```
  CloudWatchLogsRoleArn: String
  ExcludeVerboseContent: Boolean
  FieldLogLevel: String
```

I tried just adding `Retention` but got error of unsupported properties in LogConfig. I also found [this post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.LogConfig.html) where it seems possible through CDK but I am looking for cloudformation solution.